# Object lose Sculpting detail

Tags: mesh, objects, sculpting

when I switch from sculpt modus in the Object modus my mesh lose some important details[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use a Multires modifer, check the "preview" level, and increase it if you need.

However, it is useful to keep it low during Preview, to save up memory ; and use a higher level for Sculpt and Render.